# Safari flexbox child height 100% fills up all space

Tags: html, css, angular, safari, flexbox

for my angular2 app I am using flexbox only and this works fine except with Safari (and Safari mobile).
Problem with Safari is that a css height of 100% of a flex item sizes the element to 100% of main-app instead of taking other flex items into account.
Maybe it is because main-app is the first parent with position set to absolute ? I have no clue how to fix that.
Here's the code:

```
<div class='main-app flexColumn' [style.width.px]='width' [style.height.px]='height' [style.top.px]='posY' [style.left.px]='posX'>
    <menubar class='flex16_7'></menubar>
    <div class='flex81_3'>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

with:

```
.flexColumn {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}

.flex16_7 {
    flex: 1 1 16.66%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex81_3 {
    flex: 1 1 81.33%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Only Safari lets menubar fill the whole main-app.
What is going on here ?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate, because in my case it is scaled to fill up the whole space instead of not sizing bigger.